# Not sure how find function works in CPP

Tags: c++, arrays, std

I don't understand how find function is able to return position of first occurrence of element in array in this code. The code below would print 4.

From what I understand, arr should have the base address of the array and ptr should have the address of memory location of first occurence of 55 both of them when I printed came out to be : Ox470000 and Ox470010 , so my question is why we get 4 when we print (ptr-arr).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>  
using  namespace std;                 //for find()

int arr[] = { 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88 };

int main()
{
int* ptr;

ptr = find(arr, arr+8, 55);          //find first 55
cout << "First object with value 33 found at offset"
<< (ptr-arr) << endl;
cin>>arr[0];
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I find the title confusing since this question is not about the find function but about pointer arithmetic instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> both of them when I printed came out to be : Ox470000 and Ox470010 , so my question is why we get 4 when we print (ptr-arr).

Here is a quote from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Additive_operators):

> If the pointer P points to the ith element of an array, and the pointer Q points at the jth element of the same array, the expression P-Q has the value i-j, if the value fits in std::ptrdiff_t.

In other words, your subtraction does not return the offset as bytes (`0x10`) but rather as difference in index positions (`4-0`).

Answer (score 2):

You are storing integers in your array `arr`. This means that, for each position `arr[i]` there are four bytes. If you take the difference from the addresses you pointed, you'll see:

```
$ echo $(( 16#470010 - 16#470000 ))
16
```

Which means there are 16 bytes from the first to the second address. So, you in fact have the four integers when you print `(ptr - arr)`.

Answer (score 0):

When you sub a pointer form another,the result means how many this type pointed to is